# Suppose $I$ is a set and $X_i$ is a set $\forall i\in I$. Is there a set $X$ s.t. $\forall i\in I:X_i\subset X$?

Tags: set-theory

The question arose when I looked at [the most general definition of cartesian products on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products). There it is assumed that we are given "indexed family of sets" $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, which seems to be a [primitive notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion) in addition to sets and functions. So I was wondering if this is really necessary or if we can assume that there is a set $X$ such that $\forall i\in I:X_i\subset X$, meaning that we are given a function from a set $I$ to the powerset of $X$.

For example, let us consider the Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. As far as I understand the [Wikipedia article on the axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union), we have to show that there exists a set $A$ with $X_i\in A$ for all $i\in I$. Can this be rigorously proven? If there are different answers depending on the used axiomatic system, I am also interested to hear that (but please keep in mind that I am a beginner in set theory when writing your answer).

Comment: This is the [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank for the link. Indeed, the axiom of union of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory sounds very similar. But we have to show that there exists some $A$ with $X_i\in A$ for all $i$, don't we?

Comment: Good point! If $X_i$ is defined as a "function" of $i$ by some formula, the existence of such a set $A$ is the [axiom of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least a couple ways to interpret the notion of an indexed family of sets within axiomatic set theory:

- You can consider the indexed family as a function $X$ with domain $I$, and whose values are allowed to be arbitrary sets.  In other words, $(\forall a)(\forall b) ((a, b) \in X \rightarrow a \in I)$ and $(\forall i)(i \in I \rightarrow (\exists! X_i) ((i, X_i) \in X))$.  In this case, the range of the function $X$ can be constructed using the replacement axiom, and then using the union axiom on this range will give a set containing all $X_i$.
- In the case that the $X$ you have in mind is some explicit formula, then typically you can consider $X$ as being given by a first-order formula $\varphi$ with $i$ and $X_i$ as free variables, such that you can prove that this first-order formula gives a functional relation when restricted to the case $i \in I$.  Again in this situation, you can construct the image of this functional relation when applied to $I$ using the replacement axiom, and then use the union axiom to construct the containing set $X$.
- You can consider it as being given by a set $X$ and an "index" function $index : X \to I$; in this formulation, $X_i$ is interpreted as $\{ x\in X \mid index(x) = i \}$.  In this case, the containing set $X$ is built into the definition.  (This interpretation of an indexed family happens to be especially common if you study topos theory, or related topics in algebraic geometry or category theory.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Regarding the last point, isn't it a problem when the sets $X_i$ are not disjoint? AFAIU, you set$$X_i:=index^{-1}(\{i\})$$but then $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ if $i\neq j$, right?

Comment: Ah, yes, that last part does require that the $X_i$ are disjoint.  If the sets are not disjoint, then you can replace each $X_i$ with $\{ i \} \times X_i$ and get a family of disjoint sets where each is in canonical bijection with $X_i$.  (In the context this definition gets used, you usually consider each $X_i$ as a different type, so if $i \ne j$, it doesn't even make sense to ask whether $X_i$ and $X_j$ overlap.  It would be like asking, "is the President of the United States equal to $\pi$"?)

Comment: I suppose another possibility would be to allow index to be a multi-valued function $X \to \mathcal{P}(I)$, or equivalently a subset of $X \times I$.